# JSF/Primefaces datatable: Filtering based on checkbox-selected fields

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to extend my filtering function to make it more convenient.

I don't want to create a column header search and a global search input field but only one field  used for all. I want to offer an fading div with label "More" showing checkboxes for a set of fields to search against.

Now, when trying to implement this feature I need to send additional data to the server, which boxes are currently checked.

The reflection method is:

public List load(int first, int pageSize, List multiSortMeta, Map filters) {...}

... as I see, there is no way to handle this, is it? Is there any way to make the model more flexible?

It it furthermore possible to send all (but also empty filters) to the Map filter parameter of the server?

Comment: Just in the constructor pass your parameters pojo and use them in the load...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thi sounds easy. I'm coming from JSP/pure jQuery datatables and it was much more complicated.